# Unable to get PostgreSQL 9.4 to listen on port 5432

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, firewall, ports

I'm using a Linux VM (Ubuntu 15.10) to spin up a Postgres Database, and as far as I can tell, everything should be configured right.

My firewall is disabled:

```
user@UBUNTUMACHINE:~$ sudo ufw status numbered Status: inactive
```

But it's only listening on port 22

```
user@UBUNTUMACHINE:~$ netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

If I enable the firewall, and tell it to listen to 5432, it shows up in the rules:

```
user@UBUNTUMACHINE:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
5432/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

But I get the same results as above for netstat.

As far as I can tell from researching the issue, I have the correct values in my postgresql.conf file:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
```

and I've tried both IP ranges and specific IPs as trusted in the pg_hba.conf file.

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                ident sameuser

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                               peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32           md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                md5

host   all              all              10.0.0.0/255           trust
host   all              all              10.11.0.0/255          trust
host   all              all              0.0.0.0/0              trust
```

Lastly, Postgres is running, per

```
user@UBUNTUMACHINE:~$ sudo service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2017-03-08 11:09:57 CST; 57min ago
  Process: 787 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 787 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Mar 08 11:09:57 UBUNTUMACHINEsystemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Mar 08 11:09:57 UBUNTUMACHINEsystemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Mar 08 11:32:21 UBUNTUMACHINEsystemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Mar 08 11:32:26 UBUNTUMACHINEsystemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

Comment: Could you show us the error message?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for; per the 2nd code block in my submission, it's not showing as listening on port 5432.

Comment: What does `netstat -ltn` say?

Comment: Same thing as the 2nd code block above.

Comment: What is `listen_addresses` in postgresql.conf configured as?

Comment: Once again, it's up in my original post. `listen_addresses = '*'`

Comment: But is it running? `ps auxw | grep postgres` And check the postgres logfile (if any)

Comment: If I run the command `sudo service postgresql status` it says it's running; `ps auxw | grep postgres` does not show it as running, however. I tried restarting it with `sudo service postgresql start` and `sudo service postgresql restart` with no change.

Comment: The log is telling me `invalid CIDR mask in address`

Comment: `10.0.0.0/255 `255 might be larger than 32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The log is telling me invalid CIDR mask in address 10.0.0.0/255
- :: 255 might be larger than 32

Postgres refuses to start, because it refuses the netmask `/255` which islarger than the possible number of bits in the (32 bits) IP-address. You could consider this to be a bit picky for the .hba parser, but it could also be considerered a configuration error.

In any case: replace the `/255` by something sensible, like `/24` (or `/16`, since you have two of these entries) And: replace the `trust` by something more safe, after it appears to work.